# scala breeze, remove column or row from matrix

Tags: scala, breeze, scala-breeze

Is it possible to remove one or more columns or rows from a matrix in breeze?

It's possible in matlab by setting it to an empty matrix but in breeze u get a dimension error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a delete method:

```
dm.delete(row, Axis._0)
dm.delete(col, Axis._1)
```